# How do I "log in" to a web app and access subsequent pages using Java?

Tags: java, http, cookies

I want to write a Java program that'll access a few web pages that requires logging in. How would I keep the session cookie resulting from logging in so I can access those pages?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Commons HTTPClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) has all the capability to do what you want.  You can do any sort of authentication and cookie handling that you need.  Here is the code for the [CookieDemoApp](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpcomponents/oac.hc3x/trunk/src/examples/CookieDemoApp.java?view=log).

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably want to use [CookieManager](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/CookieManager.html) (you could also look at its superclass [CookieHandler](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/CookieHandler.html)). I don't know whether the standard `URLConnection` class will automatically store cookies for you, though.